# Compiling the Shogun toolbox under Windows for Matlab

Tags: matlab, compilation, machine-learning, compatibility, shogun

I was wondering if anyone of you had success and/or can help me with the Shogun library under Windows environment and Matlab interface because I don't seem to be able to compile it, though, according to the readme/manual it should work.

Things I have:

- Windows 7 64bit
- latest Shogun src package
- Matlab 2010b 64bit
- latest Cygwin (running with administrator privileges)

There are at least two errors:

- After the config script successfully detects Matlab, it fails to detect "Matlab developer support" and quits with "Error: could not find matlab developer files (e.g. mex.h)" (Matlab is in the path). The strangest thing is that after it fails, it starts and quits Matlab two times.
- But even if I run ./configure only for the basic libshogun and libshogunui interfaces (without matlab), make still fails (./configure succeeds though). While compiling, I got loads of warnings and all seem to be related with the -pthread option. And I also got several error messages all being in HDF5File.cpp, then make fails. I have cygwin's default HDF5 (version 1.8.6), the Shogun manual does not mention any incompatibilities or parameters to set up.

I only have Matlab for Windows - I tried to compile the package under Ubuntu and it failed with Octave interface but it succeeded without Octave.

Any idea is appreciated!

**edit**:

The new version of Shogun is out and produces the same error. I've tried to compile it on an other PC with the same result (though that one runs Win7x64 also)

Answer (score 1):

It may be a compiler issue. 64-bit MATLAB requires an external MEX compiler. See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/compilers/R2011a/win64.html.

Note that GCC isn't officially supported, but the GNUMEX project may help: http://gnumex.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: I think the problem comes from elsewhere because previously I successfully compiled 64bit MEX files with Matlab (using the Visual Studio engine) so this part works OK in theory.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use the latest version of Shogun, i.e. checkout the developer branch of the official git repository.

after that follow the instructions here:
https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/blob/develop/doc/md/INSTALL.md#matlab

Comment: the link is not accessible

Comment: since 2014 a lot of things changed, including the matlab interface.... matlab static interface has been removed. one should be able to have the matlab interface generated (just as python or any other) using swig (https://github.com/jaeandersson/swig) but as we dont have license for matlab we cannot test it. :(